# Do all suspend functions have a Job?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

Is `coroutineContext[Job]!!` safe to use inside a `suspend` function? Do all suspend functions have a Job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not all suspend functions have a job.

`coroutineContext` is general Kotlin mechanism to pass coroutines-related objects through `suspend` call-chain transparently and `Job` is `kotlinx.coroutines` specific abstraction.

If you've launched a coroutine via any `kotlinx.coroutines` builder which supports `Job` (e.g. using `async`, `launch` or `produce`. You can check specific builder documentation to check whether it supports `Job`), then you have `Job` in your `coroutineContext`.

But if you launched coroutine in another way, e.g. using stdlib [`buildSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/-sequence-builder/index.html), then coroutine context will not contain job.